# combine onLoad, onResize and onRefresh in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, refresh

I want a website to execute a certain jquery script (which allows me to stretch the height of a vertical menu to the height of my browser window) when the page loads and when it is resized.

So I have written a jquery of this kind:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(window).on('resize', function() {
<code to execute>
}).trigger('resize');
});
```

My problem is that this code works well when somebody loads the page or when he resizes it, but it doesn't work when one hits the refresh button. How could I make the code work also in that case?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the way I described in my own question was more than right. It worked perfectly well that way, even onRefresh. What was not making my script work properly was the fact that one of the variables I was using would change after the page had finished loading, so when I was hitting "refresh", it would give a different value than in the beginning.
So for every user of stackoverflow.com, please note that **whenever you want to set an event onLoad, onResize AND onRefresh**, the easiest and best possible way is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(window).on('resize', function() {
<code to execute>
}).trigger('resize');
});
```

In fact, what glortho was suggesting could work, but that was using another variable, and in my humble opinion, that would make the whole thing a little more redundant.
Thank you everybody for your help and for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myFn = function() { console.log('hello world') };

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  myFn();
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    myFn();
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that you likely don't want to pollute the global namespace here but this is just a simple example.

Comment: Thank you, @glortho. As a principle, this works, but it doesn't work with my script. It is as if there were too many variables. For instance, if I write the whole script and in the end an alert, the alert message works only onLoad and not onResize. If I write only one variable, it works well; if I add just one more variable, even without any calculations, the resize event stops working.
Could anybody please help me?!?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function Resize(){
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            <code to execute>
        }).trigger('resize');
    }
});
```

call this `Resize()` whenever you need. Either on load or on click.